# AJAX on load loading spinner

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I'm wanting to place something like this on my website. Here is the [codepen](http://codepen.io/msisto/pen/LntJe).

```css
@-webkit-keyframes rotate-forever {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes rotate-forever {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes rotate-forever {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
.loading-spinner {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.75s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 0.75s;
  animation-duration: 0.75s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-name: rotate-forever;
  -moz-animation-name: rotate-forever;
  animation-name: rotate-forever;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border: 8px solid #ffffff;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

body {
  background: #774CFF;
}

.loading-spinner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -15px 0 -15px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="loading-spinner"></div>
</body>
```

However, I'm wanting this to display until all my ajax has loaded on my site, I have 5-6 API GET calls, and one by rails. How would i go about this? So that it covers the whole page until its loaded.

Comment: Add the class before making the AJAX requests, remove the class when the requests complete. You haven't shown any of your JS code, so it's hard to give you an actual example.

Comment: I'm sure you know about this, but you can also use an animated gif to achieve this sort of thing more simply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Convert the `.loading-spinner` to be a mask (see the code) so it will hide the content.
2. When `ajax` done just `.hide()` it.

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'your_ajax',
  success: function() {
    hideLoader()
  },
  error: function() {
    hideLoader()
  }
});

function hideLoader() {
  $('.loading-spinner').hide();
}
```

```css
@-webkit-keyframes rotate-forever {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes rotate-forever {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes rotate-forever {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.loading-spinner {
 background: #774CFF;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

.loading-spinner:before {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.75s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 0.75s;
  animation-duration: 0.75s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-name: rotate-forever;
  -moz-animation-name: rotate-forever;
  animation-name: rotate-forever;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border: 8px solid #ffffff;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

/*body {
  background: #774CFF;
}*/

.loading-spinner:before {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -15px 0 -15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="loading-spinner"></div>
  Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum 
</body>
```